# How to make the harmonic complex tones sound comfortable?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to create a complex tone, which is consisted by several sine waves with a 220Hz fundamental frequency and 6 multiplied harmonics (at 440Hz, 660Hz, 880Hz, 1100Hz, 1320Hz, 1540Hz).

My code below generated a tone. However, it sounds very uncomfortable, and its waveform and spectrogram picture also look much intensive.

```
fs = 44100;      % [Hz] 
T = 0.5;          % [s] 
x = 0:1/fs:T;   % [s] 
 
f = 220;        % [Hz]
y = 1*sin(2*pi*f*x);
f1 = 0.2*sin(2*pi*440*x);
f2 = 0.2*sin(2*pi*660*x);
f3 = 0.2*sin(2*pi*880*x);
f4 = 0.2*sin(2*pi*1100*x);
f5 = 0.2*sin(2*pi*1320*x);
y1 = y + f1 + f2 + f3 + f4 + f5
fname = 'sin_220.wav';       
audiowrite(fname,y1,fs);
```

[image]

I found that one research group have shared similar tone materials, in which, the sine waves were synthesized regularly and sound pleasant.

[image]

My question is how to make adjustments to the code so that it looks like this.

Comment: what was uncomfortable?  were they dissonant?  they look rather periodic to me. -------- one thing that comes to mind when synthesizing tones rich in harmonics in discrete time is the aliasing of the higher harmonics that fold back to non-harmonic frequencies and sound a little dissonant or grainy or "digital".

Comment: Your code produces the correct results. Maybe you can check again the modelling/definition of the tones in the publication, just to check that nothing is missing. Btw: Your plot does not include the 1540 Hz tone, but that does not make the difference.

Comment: You are clipping and audiowrite() will give you warning about this. If you get a warning, it's typically a good idea to read and understand it.

Answer (score 1):

In Octave: `plot(y1);`

[image]

`audiowrite` will effectively clip floating point sample values to range -1 ... 1. This will sound unpleasant. You can divide your data by its maximum absolute value, before writing the audio file, to normalize it to that range.

Comment: i didn't see waveforms that exceeded the -1 to +1 range.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson there, I plotted it.

Comment: oh, you're right.  that answers it.  kui is clipping.